# Why did conda and pip just stop working? 'CompiledFFI' object has no attribute 'def_extern'

Tags: python, python-2.7, openssl, pip, anaconda

I just installed/upgraded the following packages on my system (Mac OSX 10.7.5, using python 2.7.11).

```
    package                |            build
---------------------------|-----------------
enum34-1.1.2               |           py27_0          55 KB
idna-2.0                   |           py27_0         123 KB
ipaddress-1.0.14           |           py27_0          27 KB
pyasn1-0.1.9               |           py27_0          54 KB
pycparser-2.14             |           py27_0         147 KB
cffi-1.2.1                 |           py27_0         167 KB
cryptography-1.0.2         |           py27_0         370 KB
pyopenssl-0.14             |           py27_0         122 KB
ndg-httpsclient-0.3.3      |           py27_0          30 KB
------------------------------------------------------------
                                       Total:         1.1 MB
```

Afterwards, I get the following error when trying to call pip or anaconda:

```
'CompiledFFI' object has no attribute 'def_extern'
```

What's going on and how do I fix this?

Here's the full error message:

```
    $ conda
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/User/miniconda/bin/conda", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/User/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 118, in main
    from conda.cli import main_search
  File "/Users/User/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main_search.py", line 12, in <module>
    from conda.misc import make_icon_url
  File "/Users/User/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/misc.py", line 19, in <module>
    from conda.api import get_index
  File "/Users/User/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/api.py", line 10, in <module>
    from conda.fetch import fetch_index
  File "/Users/User/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/fetch.py", line 24, in <module>
    from conda.connection import CondaSession, unparse_url, RETRIES
  File "/Users/User/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/connection.py", line 24, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/Users/User/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "/Users/User/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 54, in <module>
    import OpenSSL.SSL
  File "/Users/User/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
  File "/Users/User/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/rand.py", line 11, in <module>
    from OpenSSL._util import (
  File "/Users/User/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 6, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl.binding import Binding
  File "/Users/User/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 68, in <module>
    error=-1)
  File "/Users/User/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 57, in wrapper
    ffi.def_extern(name=name, **kwargs)(func)
AttributeError: 'CompiledFFI' object has no attribute 'def_extern'
```

Comment: Deleting the cryptography folders seemed to fix this problem but I'm not sure why.

Comment: I managed to fix all the problems I was having by deleting my miniconda folder, and then redownloading. This doesn't answer the question of what  went wrong though.

Answer (score 14):

I had this error too, but I've resolved it by upgrading cffi like so:

```
pip install --upgrade cffi
```

Comment: How come one use pip, if OP is saying it's broken.

Answer (score 12):

Upgrading cffi did not solve it for me; I did:

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove python-cryptography
```

and then reinstalled cryptography.

Comment: That works, but with the purge, these are the removed packages (at least for me):
python-cryptography
python-ndg-httpsclient
python-openssl

I suppose that they are needed to be reinstalled too.

Answer (score 10):

I solve the problem with this solution

```
easy_install -U cffi
```

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-pip/+bug/1512792/comments/11

Comment: This is what worked for me. I had a mix of homebrew- and OS X-homed python package installations and `pip` kept crashing.

Comment: After a ubuntu system upgrade I found pip was also breaking with the same error.  Upgrading with easy_install seemed to resolve all the errors.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I am answering the question this late, as all of the above answers didn't work me.

**Cause**: The probable cause was `cffi` package version i.e. 1.2.1 (in my case 1.3.0).

**Solution**: Upgrade `cffi` package. But it isn't that simple as most probably it'd have broken your `pip` as well.

First uninstall pip (for CentOS 7):

```
yum remove -y python-pip
```

Once removed, now delete the cffi package manually:

To get the exact path:

```
$ python 

>>> import cffi
>>> cffi.__path__
['/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/cffi']
```

Now go to the directory:
cd /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages - to check what cffi files and folders are there:

```
ls | grep cffi
cffi
cffi-1.3.0-py2.7.egg-info
_cffi_backend.so
```

Remove the cffi relevant files and folders:

```
rm -rf cffi cffi-1.3.0-py2.7.egg-info/ _cffi_backend.so
```

Re-installing pip:

```
yum install -y python-pip
```

Installing the latest cffi package:

```
pip install cffi==1.8.2
```

Comment: The key point that helped me (on ubuntu 14) was removing any old copies of cffi that were interfering with my tools.  Simply installing a new version of cffi did nothing for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this error in some of your virtual environments try this:

```
conda install --name <your_env> cffi
```

I had this issue in my "base" environment on Windows 7, so this helped me:

```
conda install --name base cffi
```